# SQLAlchemy 1.2 AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'Session'

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I was trying to use the code snippet from this tutorial:
http://newcoder.io/scrape/part-4/

The following is the file with the class definition:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from .models import Deals, db_connect, create_deals_table

class Test(object):

    def __init__(self, args):
        """
        Initializes database connection and sessionmaker.
        Creates deals table.
        """
        engine = db_connect()
        create_deals_table(engine)
        self.Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

    def add_item(self):

        session = self.Session()

        tester = Deals(title="test 3 deal",location='here', price=2.00)
        session.add(tester)
        session.commit()
```

When I call Test.add_item(args), the following error is generated.

```
 (sql) [bucket@localhost heap]$ python heap.py test Traceback (most
 recent call last):   File "heap.py", line 13, in <module>
     main(sys.argv)   File "heap.py", line 8, in main
     Test.add_item(args)   File "/home/bucket/src/heap/game/engine.py", line 17, in add_item
     session = self.Session() AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'Session'
```

The code worked fine and added a row when I ran the the same code as a python script with no class definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to call an instance method on the class itself: `Test.add_item(args)`

You define the method as only having `self` and no parameters. This means that you need to call it on an instance of the class, and pass it no arguments

```
test = Test()
test.add_item()
```

The reason you're getting that particular error is because you're calling the function with the list argument `args` getting used as the parameter `self`, and then the `self.Session()` line is attempting to get the attribute `Session` from the `args` object. You need to fix either the method definition or your call to it (e.g., `def add_item(self, args):`)